# Fetch Failed error after signing into the azure account using VS code Azure account extension

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vscode-extensions

I am trying to access resources from my azure cloud in my vscode using Azure Extension. I am able to sign in to my Azure account using Azure Account extension successfully, but when I try to access resources in the Azure Account extension, it gives fetch failed error, with no description.
Vscode version: 1.84.2
Azure Account Extension version: v0.11.6

What I have done,
I have uninstalled and installed all extensions and even vs code, but getting same error.

Comment: I am facing the same error of "fetch failed". My VS Code version 1.84.2 (tried on 1.83.1 as well), Azure Account extension v0.11.6, Azure Function extension v1.13.1

Comment: @Neeraj Bassi Have you installed the [Azure Resource](https://i.imgur.com/scJ6Wjp.png)  and [Azure Tools](https://i.imgur.com/WeDkcWR.png) in VS code extension.

Comment: @Neeraj Bassi How you are accessing resources?

Comment: @Neeraj Bassi Can you share the image of the error?

Comment: @Sanket Kelkar Can you share the error image?

Comment: @DasariKamali sorry for the late response. Yes I had installed Azure resources and Azure tools in VS code extension. Also now error is resolved so not able to share image of error. You can refer to this link https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3907 how it got resolved and what was the issue. Thanks for responding to my question.